# If given a basis for $V^2$, determine the conditions on the scalars such that the linear recombination of the basis also forms a basis

Tags: linear-algebra

This is how I did it, but I am not sure if this is correct.

We start with the basis $\{\vec{a},\vec{b}\}$ and want to find the condition on the scalars $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta$ such that  $\{\alpha\vec{a}-\beta\vec{b},\gamma\vec{a}+\delta\vec{b}\}$ also forms a basis.

The condition for the new vectors to form a basis is $A(\alpha\vec{a}-\beta\vec{b})+B(\gamma\vec{a}+\delta\vec{b})=\vec{O}$ . And we want to "prove" that $A=B=0$.

As a first step, I rearranged the above expression into:
$\vec{a}(A\alpha+B\gamma)+\vec{b}(B\delta-A\beta)=\vec{0}$. 
Given that $\{\vec{a},\vec{b}\}$  forms a basis, we know that the brackets are equal and equal to zero. So we arrive at $A(\alpha+\beta)=0=B(\delta-\gamma)$.

Expressing A in terms of B and putting into the first part of the above condition, I get:
$(\alpha\frac{\delta-\gamma}{\alpha+\beta}+\beta)B=0$.

Given that we want $B=0$, the condition is that the bracket isn't zero. So finally, I arrive at the following conditions:
$$\alpha\neq-\beta$$
Also, we demand that $A=B$, so then
$$\alpha+\beta=\delta-\gamma$$

What I'm not sure about here, is whether I am allowes to divide with $(\alpha+\beta)$ when expressing $A$ over $B$.

Comment: If $a,b$ is a basis, and $f:V\longrightarrow V$ is linear, requiring $f(a),f(b)$ to be a basis is the same as requiring $f$ to be invertible, that is the determinant of its matrix (for instance in the basis $a,b$) has to be non zero. With this you shoud be able to answer your question.

Comment: Either $\alpha=-\beta$ or you could divide by $\alpha+\beta$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need $\{\alpha\vec{a}-\beta\vec{b},\gamma\vec{a}+\delta\vec{b}\}$ to be a basis, i.e., we need
$$A(\alpha\vec{a}-\beta\vec{b})+B(\gamma\vec{a}+\delta\vec{b})=\vec{0}$$

to only have the trivial solution $A=B=0$. As you do, we can rearrange

$$\vec{a}(A\alpha+B\gamma)+\vec{b}(B\delta-A\beta)=\vec{0}.$$

As you also say, $\{\vec{a},\vec{b}\}$ is a basis, so both brackets are $0$. Here is where you made a mistake, because you changed the brackets. What we have is a system of equations

$$\begin{cases}\alpha A +\gamma B=0 \\ -\beta A +\delta B=0\end{cases}$$

This system has the trivial solution $A=B=0$. In order for $\{\alpha\vec{a}-\beta\vec{b},\gamma\vec{a}+\delta\vec{b}\}$ to be a basis, we need this to be the **only** solution to the system. This means that we need the columns not to be proportional:

$$\frac{\alpha}{-\beta}\ne\frac{\gamma}{\delta}$$

or equivalently, the determinant of the coefficient matrix not to be $0$:

$$\alpha\delta+\beta\gamma\ne 0$$

This is the condition you are looking for.